# In Apache Airflow, how do I pass result from macro as parameter to sql query in stored in separate .sql file

Tags: mysql, parameters, parameter-passing, airflow

I am writing a DAG using the MySqlOperator and need to pass the result from `macro.add(ds,1)` to the MySQL query.  Note the MySQL query is stored in a separate .sql file.

My DAG task is:

```py
t2 = MySqlOperator(task_id='load_dv_hub',
                   mysql_conn_id="zeus_root",
                   sql="dv_candidate_login.sql",
                   params={"window_end_date": '{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 1) }}'})
```

And, dv_candidate_login.sql is:

```sql
FROM stg_candidate_login as s
WHERE s.load_dts >= "{{ ds }}"
  AND s.load_dts < "{{ params.window_end_date }}"
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The params is not templated, meaning that you cannot use macros.ds_add in it. 
You can move your templated code into the sql file itself and that would solve the problem.

Comment: `AND s.load_dts < "{{ macros.ds_add(ds,1) }}"`